# How can I make a distinct with multiple field

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have some duplicate mail in my database but I can't remove it.
I want Select some field but without duplicate mail.

I have a request like this :

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT MAIL,
ID,
CIVILITE,
PRENOM,
NAME
FROM CONTACT WHERE CODE_PAYS = 'DE'
```

When I launch this request, my duplicate values on mail are already here.

Do you know how can I do that ?

---

**Update**: i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327492/284240) approach but i need to use it in a view:

```
ALTER VIEW ALL_VW_CONTACT_DE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
with cte as
(
   select rn = row_number() over (partition by c.Mail Order By c.Id asc), c.Mail, c.Id, c.Civilite, c.Prenom, c.Name
   from dbo.CONTACT c 
   where code_pays = 'DE'
)
select Mail, Id, Civilite, Prenom, Name
from cte
where rn = 1
```

But this doesn't work, i get this error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'MY_TABLE' because name 'CONTACT' is invalid
>   for schema binding. Name must be in two-part format and an object
>   cannot reference itself

Comment: Add sample data expected output also

Comment: Distinct is applied to all the fields. Not just the one it is beside of. So it makes sure that only one row have the same mail,id,civilite,prenom,name combination.

Comment: it's possible to add a DISTINCT just on my field mail ?

Comment: Please show some sample data.  If you have multiple records being returned, how are you determining what to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use row_number as below

```
Select top (1) with ties * from Contact
   where CODE_PAYS = 'DE'
   order by row_number() over(partition by mail order by id)
```

Answer (score 5):

> When I launch this request, my duplicate values on mail are already
>   here.

The reason for it is that `DISTINCT` doesn't work like you think. It doesn't look only at the first column after the `DISTINCT` keyword but it compares all columns in the list. So just if all are equal it is considered a duplicate.

One easy way is using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte as
(
   select rn = row_number() over (partition by c.Mail Order By c.Id asc), c.*
   from dbo.Contact c
   where Code_Pays = 'DE'
)
select Mail, Id, Civilite, Prenom, Name
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Change the `order by` if you want to take a different record, here i take the one with min-ID.

Comment: Where can I put the clause where for my code_pays ? When I after dbo.Contact this not working

Comment: @dutycorpse: in the common table expression, i have edited my answer

Comment: I have an error : Cannot schema bind view 'MY_TABLE' because name 'CONTACT' is invalid for schema binding. Name must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself

Comment: @dutycorpse: have you used `dbo.Contact` as i have shown or still `Contact`?

Comment: I used dbo.contact

Comment: @dutycorpse: edit your question, add your approach there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150198/discussion-between-dutycorpse-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1):

When you use DISTINCT with other fields, then you get only original combinations of these fields.

For this case, you should exclude all dynamic fields from query (possibly ID):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT MAIL,
CIVILITE,
PRENOM,
NAME
FROM CONTACT WHERE CODE_PAYS = 'DE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably The ID field. Since it should be unique for each row, you can't group the other fields. Remove it from the query and you should be fine.

When you do a distinct query, the trick is to look at the results and finding what columns are returning different values, that's what's differentiating them. If you add the results in your question we can help you further.